# Angular 4 universal app with @angular/cli with third party (library/component) compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, universal

I am trying to implement server side rendering using `angular universal`. With followed this post [angular-4-universal-app-with-angular-cli](https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-4-universal-app-with-angular-cli-db8b53bba07d) and this [cli-universal-demo](https://github.com/evertonrobertoauler/cli-universal-demo/tree/master) project, I encountered a problem as below.

When node starts `dist/server.js` it shows an error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) 
{ export * from ‘./scn-filter-builder’
```

`scn-filter-builder` is my module. It's written in `angular2/typescript` and `node.js` doesn't understand it.

The question is that can I set to `universal` so it will compile packages from `node_module` to `es5` by itself? Or I need to compile my component into `es5`?

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up tackling something similar to this by compiling it with Webpack. I just added a webpack.config.js with the following:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: './src/server.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    whitelist: [
      /^ngx-bootstrap/
    ]
  })],
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'server'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Add the library that needs to be compiled in the nodeExternals -> whitelist area. In my case it was ngx-bootstrap. Then just run webpack to compile your file.